# Determining bits of non-binary represented numbers

Tags: java, binary, hex

I'm reading "Thinking in Java", and there I read:

"Start with a number that has a binary one in the most significant position (hint: Use a hexadecimal constant)."

How can I know (without Google and without trying to represent some hex constants in binary system) which hexadecimal constant have which bits? Either it's most significant or some other bits.

The book assumes that for this exercise I should try out hex constants before I find one whose most significant bit is 1?

Or there is some shortcut?

I tried to think of a shortcut/way of knowing how to figure out what value has most significant bit of a hex constant...

Comment: There's info missing. For instance, the *type* of "number" makes a difference. Is it `byte` or `int` or what? Missing context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what is the most significant bit of a particular number represented in hexadecimal number system.

Suppose the type is `int`, although I don't see how it's important.

Comment: Let's take `byte` to keep it simple. Anything >= hex value `0x80` will have the most significant bit set. And that will make the `byte`'s value negative. So if you take say `0x7F`, you will know it's *not* set

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what you want but it sounds like a masking exercise. Please show some input examples and expected output.

Comment: OK, so I should look at hex representation of type's maxvalue and then reduce it by one. I think I got it.

Thanks, g00se.

Comment: Not *quite*. Since all types are signed apart from `char`, the max value doesn't have the bit set. If you want it unset then it's <= MAX_VALUE. But all values < 0 *also* have the most sig. bit set

Comment: Yeah, I know, of course, that absolute MSB is set for all negative numbers. But I think the book meant the bit next-to-the-right of absolute MSB.

Comment: "the max value doesn't have the bit set"


Wait, let's take your 0x7F as byte's maxvalue. It's clear that its MSB will be 1, because max value "fills" all bits apart from sign bits with ones.

For `int` it's the same: binary representation of 2147483647 is 1111111111111111111111111111111. So MSB is also 1.

Anyways, isn't maxvalue of all integer types all ones?

@g00se @user16320675

Comment: I don't know what the book means but using the term "most significant bit" in an alternative way would be inclined to confuse

Comment: OK, so post a response so I can choose your reply as the best and close the question. @g00se

Comment: Well, under MSB I don't mean sign bit, which is obviously zero for all positive integer numbers. And that is 1 for all negative numbers. That's always clear.

I mean the-next-to-MSB bit...

@user16320675

Comment: @user16320675 Yeah, I'm sorry, but it's just clear for me that the bit mentioned in the book is next-to-the-right-from-MSB. :)

Comment: No, if it's Exercise 11, Eckel *literally* means the MSB. For fun, try it with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: @g00se Then why he says like "FIND a number whose MSB is 1"??? It's clear that it's just any negative number. And you don't need hex constants for this.

Comment: "Find" would essentially mean "pick" or "choose". I haven't read on (I just had a quick look) but he will probably discuss the difference between `>>` and `>>>`. For fun, check the output of `Integer.MIN_VALUE >> 1` and its almost comical difference between `Integer.MIN_VALUE >>> 1`

Comment: @g00se

I'm sorry, I haven't ran Eclipse, but it seems to me that `Integer.MIN_VALUE >> 1` will change nothing while `Integer.MIN_VALUE >>> 1` will make minimum negative integer maximum positive integer...

Comment: Well if that's what you think, you'd better find out if you're right ;)

Comment: @g00se On, now I checked. I thought `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `1111111111111111111111111111111`, but it's actually `10000000000000000000000000000000`

Lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integral types, you will know the most significant bit is set when:

1. The number is negative
2. The number exceeds the `MAX_VALUE` attribute of the object wrapper class of your primitive type

For the purposes of the above, I exclude `char` since its function is not normally one of manipulating numbers in a normal way